# How to add IMethodInterceptor Listener to the testng suite programmatically without using <listener> tag in xml file

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have implemented `IMethodInterceptor` listener in my framework to apply test groups at run time from **Jenkins**. I had to use `<listener>` tag in all my testing xmls to include this listener. It will be a huge task for me. I want to assign it via JAVA itself.

I tried this:

```
iTestContext.getSuite().addListener(new MethodInterceptorListener());
iTestContext.getSuite().addListener(new InvokedMethodListener());
```

This is working for `InvokedMethodListener` but not for `MethodInterceptorListener`.

1. Any idea how can I make it work?
2. Why this `addListener()` method which is working for `InvokedMethodListener` is not working for `MethodInterceptorListener`?

Comment: Just register it using the service loader framework?

Comment: Official TestNG documentation on ServiceLoader seems to be too complex for me. I will be running my scripts in a Jenkins machine. Will it work fine? If so, please share me an example, will try it.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
iTestContext.getSuite().addListener(new MethodInterceptorListener());
```

This does not work because listener of type `IMethodInterceptor` (as well as few other types) is not handled in `ISuite.addListener()`. Whereas you could add a listener to `TestRunner` which is the implementation of `ITestContext`.

You could try the below code and it would work.

```java
if(iTestContext instanceof TestRunner) {
    ((TestRunner) iTestContext).addListener(new MethodInterceptorListener()); 
}
```

If you are using java 16 do:

```java
if(iTestContext instanceof TestRunner t) {
    t.addListener(new MethodInterceptorListener()); 
}
```